# Why are these patterns not being matched in this ANTLR production?

Tags: java, parsing, antlr, grammar, antlr4

I'm using the ANTLR v4 Java grammar, available [here](https://github.com/antlr/grammars-v4/blob/master/java/Java.g4), to parse Java code. One of the productions looks like this:

```
expression
    :   primary
    |   expression '.' Identifier
    |   expression '.' 'this'
    |   expression '.' 'new' nonWildcardTypeArguments? innerCreator
    |   expression '.' 'super' superSuffix
    |   expression '.' explicitGenericInvocation
    |   expression '[' expression ']'
    |   expression arguments
    |   // Lots of other patterns...
    ;
```

`expression '.' Identifier` matches a simple member access, and `expression arguments` matches a method call. You can view the full source of this production [here](https://github.com/antlr/grammars-v4/blob/master/java/Java.g4#L497-L538).

For the purposes of syntax highlighting, I want to introduce additional redundant patterns to detect what I call *named method invocations*. `bar()` or `foo.bar()` would count as a named method invocation, with `bar` being the name of the method. For such expressions I want `bar` to be colored green, even though identifiers are normally colored white. However, in `foo.bar` or `foo.bar[0]()`, nothing should be colored green. In the former `bar` is not calling a method, and in the latter `bar[0]` is not a valid identifier.

I added these two extra patterns before `expression arguments` (note: `arguments` is synonymous with `'(' expressionList? ')'` in the original source code):

```
expression
    :   // ...
    |   expression '[' expression ']'
    |   Identifier arguments namedMethodInvocationStub // Detect bar()
    |   expression '.' Identifier arguments namedMethodInvocationStub // Detect (some().complicated().expression()).bar()
    |   expression arguments
    |   // ...
    ;

namedMethodInvocationStub
    :
    ;
```

(Here, `namedMethodInvocationStub` is an extra dummy production I've added. The idea is I can override `VisitExpression` and check if the last child is a `namedMethodInvocationStub`. If so, then we've matched a named method invocation, so go through all direct children of type `Identifier` and color them green. Anyhow, this is just to demystify what that is, it's not directly related to my question below.)

I expected this rule change to make `foo.bar()`, which had previously parsed as `(expression '.' Identifier) arguments`, now parse as `expression '.' Identifier arguments namedMethodInvocationStub`. However, it still parses the same way as before, whether or not I remove the `namedMethodInvocationStub`. Why is this?

Answer (score 0):

I believe you can't match empty rule/token (namedMethodInvocationStub) in ANTLR (or any other lexer)

[ANTLR: empty condition not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13289263/antlr-empty-condition-not-working)

[What is the equivalent for epsilon in ANTLR BNF grammar notation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5522574/what-is-the-equivalent-for-epsilon-in-antlr-bnf-grammar-notation)

Do you see any errors/warning during ANTLR code generation phase?

Comment: It seems to be happening with or without `namedMethodInvocationStub`, though.

Comment: I didn't find pattern "expression arguments" at the location you've provided https://github.com/antlr/grammars-v4/blob/master/java/Java.g4#L497-L538

Comment: Sorry, I tweaked the code a little bit to make it neater. `arguments` is another nonterminal ([here](https://github.com/antlr/grammars-v4/blob/master/java/Java.g4#L604-L606)) synonymous with `'(' expressionList? ')'`.

Comment: @JamesKo, you can try to use "marker" #methodInvocation at "|   expression '(' expressionList? ')'" to handle that in different manner in your visitor code.

Comment: What does `#methodInvocation` do? I have not seen that syntax before.

Comment: OK thanks, I just found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22002799/antlr4-how-to-know-which-alternative-is-chosen-given-a-context) which explains what pound signs do. However, these patterns are still not being matched-- all of the method calls are still parsing as `expression arguments`. Can you tell me why?